# Difference between git status branch.upstream and branch.ab

Tags: git

I'm just reading the `git status` docs (ver 2.34.0), and I found something like this:

```
Line                                     Notes
------------------------------------------------------------
# branch.oid <commit> | (initial)        Current commit.
# branch.head <branch> | (detached)      Current branch.
# branch.upstream <upstream_branch>      If upstream is set.
# branch.ab +<ahead> -<behind>           If upstream is set and the commit is present.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So **theoretically, `branch.upstream` and `branch.ab` appear upon different conditions** but from my tests, they always appear at the same time. 
Can someone make a condition where **only `branch.upstream` appears**? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I did some more experiments and found out that ab is also based on the refs/remotes/ directory's branch ref files. These files contain the latest commits on that branch on origin. So when they exist, ab also exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand a bit on my comment on LeGEC's answer here.

Suppose you have a repository:

```
$ cd <somewhere-with-repository>
```

and that repository has a remote name, e.g., `origin`, and the remote has some branch(es).  We now do your `git status --porcelain=v2` to get an example output:

```
$ git status --porcelain=v2 -b
# branch.oid 2808ac68000c62c3db379d73e3b7df292e333a57
# branch.head master
# branch.upstream origin/master
# branch.ab +0 -0
```

This particular repository has only `master` and `origin/master`:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

so now we need to create a new branch to trigger your desired condition:

```
$ git switch -c foo
Switched to a new branch 'foo'
$ git status --porcelain=v2 -b
# branch.oid 2808ac68000c62c3db379d73e3b7df292e333a57
# branch.head foo
```

We now need to set the upstream to `origin/foo`, but `git branch -u` refuses to do it:

```
$ git branch -u origin/foo
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/foo' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

But we can work around that using the underlying `branch.foo.remote` and `branch.foo.merge` settings:

```
$ git config branch.foo.remote origin
$ git config branch.foo.merge refs/heads/foo
# branch.oid 2808ac68000c62c3db379d73e3b7df292e333a57
# branch.head foo
# branch.upstream origin/foo
```

Using `git branch -vv` shows us this:

```
$ git branch -vv
* foo    2808ac6 [origin/foo: gone] add xheap, for a priority queue for py3k
  master 2808ac6 [origin/master] add xheap, for a priority queue for py3k
```

This is what we'd see as well with `git push -u origin foo` followed by a deletion of `origin/foo` that prunes our own `refs/remotes/origin/foo`.

(It's a bit curious that `git branch -u` won't let you set up this situation directly, since it would obviate the need for `git push -u` later and hence be useful in scripts.  But the lower-level `git config` commands do let you set up this situation.)

Answer (score 3):

You may set an upstream to a branch :

```
git branch -u some/upstream
```

If you choose an upstream which doesn't exist yet (for example: `git branch -u origin/doesnt/exist/yet`), you should be in that "If upstream is set." without "... and the commit is present."

*[edit] :* actually (as noted by @torek), `git branch -u some/upstream` will check that `some/upstream` exists, and will not allow you to track a non existing branch.
"branch tracking" is stored in your repository's configuration, you can edit your configuration file to forcibly set a non existing remote branch :

```
[branch "test"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/doesnt/exist
```

---

In practice, however, you will not often be this situation.

You will generally set branch tracking through commands such as `git checkout <origin/somebranch>` or `git push -u ...`, both of which make sure that the "remote branch" exists at the time the link is created or updated.

The situation may happen when a remote branch gets deleted by someone else, and one of your local branches is still set to track that remote branch.

Comment: Note that `git branch --set-upstream-to` refuses to take a remote-tracking name that doesn't exist (yet or any more), but the underlying mechanical bits will take the pieces, and as you say, it tends to happen when the other remote's branch gets deleted and you done a prune.